# Remove / Rewrite 2 directory names from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to rewrite or redirect URLs like this:

> http://www.mydomain.com/shop/product/keep-this-please

to

> http://www.mydomain.com/keep-this-please

and the htaccess in my shop (Magento) directory already has this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /shop/

## always send 404 on missing files in these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I rewrite just the URLs with the /shop/product/ in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this line just below RewriteBase line:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```