# Removing 2 folders from URL and redirecting to page

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a new web app and this is how my project folders look like:

[image: I added an image because I thought it would be easier to explain the structure this way]

So as you can see I have renamed that htaccess in the root folder because I am not using that one and I am using the one situated inside of the public folder. I am trying to change my URLs from this:

http://example.site/public/pages/about

to:

http://example.site/about

I was able to remove the .php from the file extensions but the code I added to remove the folders from the URL is not working.

Note: in the root folder (App/index.php) the index.php file simply has this:

```
<?php

header('Location: public/pages');
```

so I am just using this to send to the correct folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /App/public/

RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have seen this question/answer from this url:

[Remove / Rewrite 2 directory names from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710981/remove-rewrite-2-directory-names-from-url)

but it is not working for me. Looking forward to anyone who can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ``htdocs/app/`is your`DocumentRoot`for`app.blu` domain.

Inside `htdocs/app/public/.htaccess` you may use this code:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# if URL has /pages/ then remove and redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# landing page for app subdomain to show index.php
RewriteRule ^$ pages/index.php [L]

# check & rewrite if a matching .php file exists in pages/ subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

---

Besides this you will need to use this code in `htdocs/app/.htaccess`:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# send all the traffic to /public/
RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: it does not work for me, it still shows the same url and even if I remove them it still redirects to that same url that has public/pages/ in it. When I added the other htdocs in the root of htdocs folder it shows an internal error and does not load the page at all

Comment: `it still shows the same url `: What URL do you ouse to test this? Make sure you don't have any other rule except these rules while testing.

Comment: I simply remove the /public/pages/ from the url and test that but it still redirects to that same URL because the index.php file in the root folder sends to that path, if I dont send to that path then nothing shows on the screen, its the same structure like the image i provided. No other rules are there except for what you provided

Comment: So if you are loading `http://example.site/about` then that URL is not supposed to change right? It should just show content from `http://example.site/App/public/pages/about.php`

Comment: if i try and load http://example.site/about then it says URL not found on this server, if load just http://example.site/ it redirects to http://example.site/public/pages/

Comment: Looks like old cache. Can you test from command line curl or from a new browser.

Comment: same thing on a different browser, please note the App i named is in the url so its like this http://app.blu/public/pages/about so app is the root folder if that makes a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231519/discussion-between-anubhava-and-blu3).